# React-native opens debug like this?

Tags: react-native

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I turn on debugging, chroem is like this. The code in the console doesn't show up.

Comment: Use pause on caught exception

Comment: In the index above in this file, I don't know how to catch err

Comment: The error is thrown from /app/index.js not /index.js

Comment: ok , i should have try

Comment: it‘s not /app/index.js

Comment: Stop and start the packager again

Answer (score 0):

we should change 127.0.0.1 tolocalhost